# Ошибка в GitHub 403 через https

Tags: git, github

Добрый день!
Создал локальное хранилище.
Клонировал удаленный репозиторий, `push` через `https` выдает ошибку :

> "unable to access ' ': The requested URL returned error: 403"

Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И почему у мастера восклицательный знак?

Comment: [http-код состояния 403](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#403) — это требование аутентификации.

Comment: Пользуйтесь консолью, там все понятно. )

Answer (score 1):

судя по картинке, вы используете gui-программу [*smartgit*](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/).

инструкция по интеграции этой прогаммы с сервером *github* подробно описана в её документации: https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/GitHub+integration